# What to do with questions like these (Big-O etc)?

Tags: discussion, scope

Here is a question that I don't think belongs on SO (yes it is on topic *per se*, but I think not useful to the site or user): [Compare growth of function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30714239/1075247)

I looks like it should be on [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) or [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com).

I would normally flag it as 'off-topic' but none of the options fit (this is not blatently off-topic to not be about software in general). And I think from past experience the mods don't want to deal with this. And everyone is sick of people asking to move stuff to Programmers.

So what should I do? I've DVed it, but I feel like it could be rescued by moving it somewhere more appropriate where it'll get more love.

Advice? This [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/175002) says this:

> The ultimate goal is for each site to have a **laser sharp focus** and keep its experts engaged at all times. People question the need to have a site like Programmers all the time, to which I respond that I really don't want my conceptual questions on Stack Overflow, where they will quickly be buried under tons of questions on how to concatenate a string in PHP or fade an element with jQuery. Stack Overflow is gigantic and you may get answers in seconds, but if you think about it you, the asker, only need one answer. And chances are that you'll get a **far better answer on Programmers**, even if you'll have to wait a couple of days (or more).

(Emphasis mine)

Comment: It is pretty unlikely to be welcome on either of them, ultimately they are not the garbage dump for questions we don't want.  Big-Oh without heavy theoretically underpinning is something every programmer needs to know, that does make it on topic for SO.  Whether a student's homework assignment is on topic has been debated at length many times before but not what you are asking.

Comment: related: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Answer (score 6):

To retort:  most everyone is sick of moving the *wrong* stuff to Programmers.  This is a good example of content that shouldn't be moved over there, as it doesn't really relate to whiteboard problems; it's mathematical as opposed to anything to specifically do with programming.

It's also dodgy at best on Computer Science, as the question basically says, "I think the answer is ____, am I right?", where the answer is either empirically yes or no.

*Perhaps* it could find life on Mathematics.SE, as it does ask directly about limits and other mathematical concepts.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a custom off topic reason for questions like this, explaining why it's off topic.

Comment: I don't think I can do that at my rep (?) The off-topic sub-menu has no free-text fields. The only free-text is to flag for moderator attention, almost every time I've tried that it's been rejected.

Comment: @Pureferret When you hit 3k rep, the "Blatently Off-topic" spot is replaced with a new free form field for custom off-topic reasons. So, no, you can't currently do that. (And definitely don't use the mod attention one for this. It's extra work for them when the community can handle it.) In the meantime, Servy has handled it with their own custom close reason.

Comment: @Kendra thanks didn't realise. I';m a high-rep user elsewhere on the site and I've forgotten what tools I have to look forward to.